# Checking if string is TimeSpan

Tags: c#, .net

I am importing data from an Excel file and i need to check if the data i am importing is a TimeSpan or a regular string. Because the data can be either **07:00:00** or **D2 07:00**. In the excel file some of the fields are formatted to be **tt:mm** but others are plain text fields.

My code look like this:

```
 public void ReadExcelFile()
        {
            string filename = @"C:\Temp\Copy2.xlsx";
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\""))
            {
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    string sqlCmd1 = "SELECT  * FROM [Sheet1$]";
                    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlCmd1, connection))
                    {
                        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                        using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                alias = "" + reader[3];
                                codeT = "" + reader[4];
                                dtTruck = "" + reader[5];
                                codeP = "" + reader[6];
                                dtPlane = "" + reader[7];
                                dtDealer = "" + reader[8];

                                TimeSpan ts;
                                bool TruckisValid = TimeSpan.TryParse(dtTruck, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out ts);
                                bool PlaneisValid = TimeSpan.TryParse(dtPlane, out ts);
                                if (TruckisValid )
                                {
                                    truck = TimeSpan.FromDays(Convert.ToDouble(dtTruck));
                                }
                                else if (PlaneisValid)
                                {
                                    plane = TimeSpan.FromDays(Convert.ToDouble(dtPlane));
                                }
                                else
                                {

                                }

                                if (dtTruck == "" && dtPlane == "")
                                {
                                    dtTruck = "";
                                    dtPlane = "";
                                }
                                else if (dtTruck != "")
                                {
                                    truck = TimeSpan.FromDays(Convert.ToDouble(dtTruck));
                                    dtPlane = "";
                                }
                                else if (dtPlane != "")
                                {
                                    plane = TimeSpan.FromDays(Convert.ToDouble(dtPlane));
                                    dtTruck = "";
                                }


                                SearchForAdrIDAndCustID(Convert.ToString(reader[0]), Convert.ToString(reader[3]));
                                InsertData(custID, "" + reader[3], adrID, truck, codeT, plane, codeP, dtDealer);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR in ReadExcelFile() method. Error Message : " + exception.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see i have tried to use a bool to determine if the imported field is a timespan or not. But the bool is always false.

can anyone help ?

Comment: Put a break point and see what values you get in `dtTruck` and `dtPlane`, because you should be able to parse `"07:00:00"` using TimeSpan.TryParse

Comment: Please use `TimeSpan.ParseExact` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992370.aspx Don't waste time on regex.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219191/how-to-check-if-a-string-value-is-in-a-correct-time-format

Answer (score 2):

Here's the relevant part of your question:

```
TimeSpan ts;
bool TruckisValid = TimeSpan.TryParse(dtTruck, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out ts);
bool PlaneisValid = TimeSpan.TryParse(dtPlane, out ts);
if (TruckisValid )
{
    truck = TimeSpan.FromDays(Convert.ToDouble(dtTruck));
}
else if (PlaneisValid)
{
    plane = TimeSpan.FromDays(Convert.ToDouble(dtPlane));
}
else
{

}
```

1. You're reusing the same `TimeSpan` variable `ts` for two different fields. I assume that you use it just to test if it can be parsed. Instead you should use the parsed `TimeSpan`.
2. You're testing for `TimeSpan` but **you're converting it to `double`**. It is either convertable to TimeSpan or to double not both.

So maybe this approach is better:

```
double d;
TimeSpan ts;
bool TruckisValidDouble = false;
bool TruckisValidTimeSpan = TimeSpan.TryParse(dtTruck, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out ts);
if(!TruckisValidTimeSpan)
{
    TruckisValidDouble = double.TryParse(dtTruck, out d);
}
// use approapriate variables
```

**From comments:**

> the reason for converting it to double is because when i import the
>   data from my excel file it has the percentage value of 07:00:00 witch
>   is 0,29166666667. So im converting the double value to a timespan.

But you cannot check for `TimeSpan` and parse to `double` or vice-versa. If you know that it's a `TimeSpan` via `TryParse` use the `TimeSpan` variable directly. Otherwise `double.TryParse` and use that variable afterwards.

For example:

```
if(!TruckisValidTimeSpan  && TruckisValidDouble)
{
    ts = TimeSpan.FromHours(d * 24);
}
```

Comment: the reason for converting it to double is because when i import the data from my excel file it has the percentage value of 07:00:00 witch is  0,29166666667. So im converting the double value to a timespan.

Comment: Ha? But you use `TimeSpan.FromDays(...)` which has nothing whatsoever to do with percentage...

Comment: @Lahib: But you cannot check for timspan and parse to double or vice-versa. If you know that it's a TimeSpan via `TryParse` use the TimeSpan variable directly. Otherwise `double.TryParse` and use that variable afterwards. You can use `TimeSpan.FromHours(d * 24)`. Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to check if your value is a TimeSpan like so:

```
Regex reg = new Regex("^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$"); 
bool TruckIsValid = reg.IsMatch(dtTruck);
```