# How to check if a string value is in a correct time format?

Tags: c#, string, validation, time

Is there a possibility to check wether a string is in a valid time format or not?

```
Examples:
12:33:25 --> valid
03:04:05 --> valid
3:4:5    --> valid
25:60:60 --> invalid
```

Comment: is there any date time module in csharp?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710501/how-to-perform-c-sharp-time-validation-in-hhmmss-format

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to perform c# time validation in HHMMSS format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710501/how-to-perform-c-sharp-time-validation-in-hhmmss-format)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Additional method can be written for the purpose of the string time format validation. `TimeSpan` structure has got `TryParse` method which will try to parse a string as `TimeSpan` and return the outcome of parsing *(whether it succeeded or not)*.

*Normal method:*

```
public bool IsValidTimeFormat(string input)
{
    TimeSpan dummyOutput;
    return TimeSpan.TryParse(input, out dummyOutput);
}
```

*Extension method (must be in separate non-generic static class):*

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static bool IsValidTimeFormat(this string input)
    {
        TimeSpan dummyOutput;
        return TimeSpan.TryParse(input, out dummyOutput);
    }
}
```

Calling the methods for the existing `string input;` *(lets imagine it's initialized with some value)*.

*Normal method:*

`var isValid = IsValidTimeFormat(input);`

*Extension method:*

`var isValid = DateTimeExtensions.IsValidTimeFormat(input);`

*or*

`var isValid = input.IsValidTimeFormat();`

---

**UPDATE: .NET Framework 4.7**

Since the release of .NET Framework 4.7, it can be written a little bit cleaner because output parameters can now be declared within a method call. Method calls remain the same as before.

*Normal method:*

```
public bool IsValidTimeFormat(string input)
{
    return TimeSpan.TryParse(input, out var dummyOutput);
}
```

*Extension method (must be in separate non-generic static class):*

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static bool IsValidTimeFormat(this string input)
    {
        return TimeSpan.TryParse(input, out var dummyOutput);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`TimeSpan.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`TimeSpan.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods for that.

These methods uses this format.

`[ws][-]{ d | [d.]hh:mm[:ss[.ff]] }[ws]`

Elements between in square brackets (`[` and `]`) are optional.

```
TimeSpan.Parse("12:33:25") // Parsing fine
TimeSpan.Parse("03:04:05") // Parsing fine
TimeSpan.Parse("3:4:5") // Parsing fine
TimeSpan.Parse("25:60:60") // Throws overflow exception.
```

Comment: TryParse returns true for 121212 but it's not a valid time for SQL Server. How can I filter them too?

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't want to write methods, you could always check and see if converts successfully.  If needed you can use a bool to show whether or not it was valid.

```
bool passed = false;
string s = String.Empty;
DateTime dt;
try{
     s = input; //Whatever you are getting the time from
     dt = Convert.ToDateTime(s); 
     s = dt.ToString("HH:mm"); //if you want 12 hour time  ToString("hh:mm")
     passed = true;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Timespan is a piece of time not a valid time of the day. it accepts "300" as "300:00:00" but it's not want.

This works for you

```
bool IsTime(string myValue) {

    bool Succeed = true;

    try {
        DateTime temp = Convert.ToDateTime(myValue);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Succeed = false;
    }

    return Succeed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How I solved it using TryParseExact

// Ask user to provide time

```
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a time in the format HH:MM");

string timeInput = Console.ReadLine();
```

// Indicate the time format you want

```
  string timeFormat = "HH:mm";
  CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("jp-JP");
```

// Check if it matches

```
  if(DateTime.TryParseExact(timeInput, timeFormat, culture, 
  DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime result) == true)

  {

   Console.WriteLine("You got it");

   };
```

Check this post for more details https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a72bb508-e35e-4632-b74a-efb6df04c4ab/c-check-if-time-from-textbox-is-a-valid-time?forum=aspgettingstarted